# Problema con Trigger MySQL y last_insert_id() desde Stored Procedure implementado en Java

Tags: java, mysql, trigger

Estoy insertando datos desde una Aplicación `Java`

```
DataBaseConnection._callableStatment = DataBaseConnection.connDB.prepareCall("{call addEmployee(?,?,?,?,?)}");
```

y los inserta correctamente, pero el `Trigger` que estoy utilizando me inserta el dato erróneo

**Trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateIDTextEmployee BEFORE INSERT ON employees FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  /*En esta parte se supone que obtengo el ultimo ID, hasta este punto es 15*/
  SET @_idEmployee = (SELECT last_insert_id() FROM employees LIMIT 1);
  /*Aquí debe de actualizar el campo a 16 (15 +1)*/
  SET NEW.idSecondary = CONCAT("SB",LPAD(@_idEmployee+1,7,"0"));
END
```

Pero me aparece `SB00000001` en lugar de `SB000000016`. Si hago la inserción desde `Workbench` aparentemente todo bien.

Comment: Por qué dices que estas insertando en el `trigger` si no hay un `INSERT`, solo veo una consulta que pregunta  que después de insertar en tu tabla haga algo, que es setear valores, además no es necesario darle un `LIMIT 1` a un `last_insert_id()`, si solo devuelve un valor que es el último id insertado.

Comment: Quiza redacte mal mi pregunta, el trigger se dispara al insertar,pero antes el trigger  ingresa el dato al campo `idSecondary`. Ahora, el `last_insert_id()` me repite el id 3 veces, desconozco el por que, pero también desde la aplicación no realiza su función correctamente, a diferencia de el propio `Workbench`. Estuve consultando aquí mismo el problema y hay inestabilidad con la propiedad `last_insert_id()`